# unhandled js exception methods.forEach is not a function (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I just updated React Native to 0.34.1 and also updated all dependencies.
But now I get this error:

[image]

Comment: did you reach anything?

Comment: for me it didn't work even after upgrading to 0.35 but then it worked after I added libReact.a from my pods file

Answer (score 0):

Running again `react-native run-ios` remove this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set the Run scheme in the iOS Xcode Project to "Release". Change it back to "Debug" and run `react-native run-ios` again.